# How to check if a DOM element contains a string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to see whether a string is contained within an element? Specifically a link?

For example:

```
<a href="#">Some text foo_string more text</a>
```

will return "a" as the element. jQuery or PHP - doesn't matter. Thank you!

**Clarification:**

What I want to know  is the element that contains foo_string. NOT whether an element contains the string.

Comment: Have you looked into jQuery?

Comment: you mean you want the dom element which contains the string you're looking for? or just the name of the element?

Comment: Just the element Marc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
if($('a').text().length < 1 ){
   alert("empty")
}else{
  alert("not");
}
```

### Updated

```
$(":contains('Some text foo_string')"); //this get all the element with the text in it
```

You can use `.prop('tagName')` to get the tag name.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/C96r8/)
|
[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/C96r8/1/)

Answer (score 5):

**Checking if the element contains the string**

To check if an element meets this criterion, try the jQuery [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
if ($('#some-element').is(':contains("foo_string")')) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Note this selector is case-sensitive.

---

**Selecting the element(s) that contain(s) the string**

To select elements that meet this criterion, simply pass the selector as an argument to the main jQuery function as you would with any other selector:

```
var element_with_foo = $(':contains("foo_string")');
```

Remember it's recommended to limit the scope of the selection, otherwise it will apply to the entire DOM.

Comment: This is NOT what I am asking. As I added in the question, I want to know the element what contains a particular string. So it could be div, a, or anything else.

Comment: Thanks Boaz, would you happen to know if there is a PHP DOMDocument equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the innerText or textContent DOM properties and JavaScript's regex methods.

e.g.

```
var el = document.getElementById('my-link');
var txt = el.innerText;
return txt.match(/str/);
```

It's simpler to use jQuery here, but this is a pure JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

`if ($('a').html().indexOf('foo_string') != -1) // doSomething`